# how to use keyup, select , change events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have render dynamic control for input , dropdown, datepicker in html with javascript. the control render by user side so we dont know what is type of control render at this time how to rise the key events and change and select events.

for eg: input box means using keyup event.

```
this.on(target ,"keyup",function)
```

how to use in same line events for  based on control render(dropdown and date picker)

Comment: handle the events with the container element, something like `$("#parentContainerId input").on("keyup",function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said
*I have render dynamic control for input , dropdown, datepicker in html with javascript.*

For this you can call a function which can take an argument to be passed in and that could let you decided what should be done with that controll:

suppose, you have appended your inputs and just after it you can call a function with some args or send an object with some specific information like:

```
$(parentElem).append(control); // suppose you have appended the type text

bindEvent({ctrlId:control.id, parentEl:parentElem, ctrlEvent:controlEv});  

function bindEvent(obj){
   $(obj.parentEl).on(obj.event, '#'+obj.ctrlId, function(e){
       // here you can check for e.type == "change/click/focus/keyup" etc
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set listeners like this:

```
$('#' + target.Id).keyup(function(){
    //do whatever
});

$('#' + target.Id).change(function(){
    //do whatever
});
```